# How do you add a role to every user in a guild? (discord js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How would you be able to do the above in NodeJS?

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Code I have used:
`if (command === "addrole") { let roller = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "️ Changes & Fixes"); for (let member of message.guild.members.cache) { message.guild.member.roles.add(roller); } }`

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried so far?

Comment: But it comes with "add is undefined"

Comment: Next time edit new info into your question

Comment: I joined a few mins ago

Comment: Many new folks to the site can get disappointed because they don't understand how the site works. We are all actually encouraged to interact with questions, even closing them, if they are felt to be not on-topic. Please check out the [ask] and the [help] to learn how the site works and to avoid getting disappointed or frustrated yourself.

Comment: And also, yes, please [edit] your question and add relevant information, code and full error messages to the question itself, not in comments, so that the question is clearer and easier to answer. Much luck!

Comment: Will do, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`<cache>` is a collection not an array, the do have built in `.each` method though.

```js
if (command === "addrole") {
    let roller = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "️ Changes & Fixes");
    message.guild.members.cache.each(member => member.roles.add(roller));
}
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each

Comment: `if (command === "addrole") {
let roller = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === " Announcements");
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
    message.delete()
    member.roles.add(roller);
  })
}`

Yeah understood, used the above code after finding the fix.